# wget returned a webpage instead of a file?

Tags: linux, wget

I want to download the an executable file from LunarG with 'wget' command.

I tried the following and the outcome is shown:

```
$ wget https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home#sdk/downloadConfirm/1.0.61.1/linux/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.0.61.0.run -P $HOME/Downloads/
--2017-10-03 12:43:32--  https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home
Resolving vulkan.lunarg.com (vulkan.lunarg.com)... 52.26.34.138, 35.167.57.241
Connecting to vulkan.lunarg.com (vulkan.lunarg.com)|52.26.34.138|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6197 (6.1K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/home/sunbear/Downloads/home’

home                            100%[======================================================>]   6.05K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2017-10-03 12:43:33 (597 MB/s) - ‘$HOME/Downloads/home’ saved [6197/6197]
```

Instead of getting a file called vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.0.61.0.run, I got a HTML document called home.

I am able to click the hyperlink given on the website to download the file, however, I just could not download it via commandline which is surprising.

**Question**: How can I download this file using wget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link triggers the download, if you start the download in Chrome you can see the real download URL is:

https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/download/1.0.61.1/linux/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.0.61.1.run

instead of:

https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home#sdk/downloadConfirm/1.0.61.1/linux/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.0.61.0.run

The URL is shown in the download page as below:
[image]

Comment: I was not able to see the difference in Chromium during the download. Appreciate you showing me the way. I have used the URL and it works. Thanks. ;)

Comment: No problem, the URL shows in the download page, but not on the bottom bar bit

Comment: I installed google chrome and tried it. Can you tell me where is this download page that you mentioned? I could not see it during the download..

Comment: If you press `Ctrl+J` in either browser it should show up (Tested on Linux)